# Server Error in Default Deployment of Azure Flask Web App

Tags: python, azure, flask

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app within Azure, using the pre made template created by Azure.

I can't get a simple...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

To do anything. To simplify further still, even the pre made deployment returns an error...[image]

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something very fundamental here.
Using FTP I can see the files that Azure is creating - sure does look like there should be a nice little demo site.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers, Ben

Comment: Now it appears that it's working fine. Deploy a pre-built Flask app, click the link, up it pops just fine. I can't see where I was possibly going wrong - a rare occasion when the fault was not with me, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think the issue was caused by some incorrect configuration in the `web.config` & the `Application Settings` of your WebApp settings. Please try to refer to the [blog](https://sunithamk.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/build-your-flask-application-on-windows-azure-websites/) to resolve it.

Meanwhile, I don't know what `pre made template created by Azure` you used. I tried to create a new Azure WebApp for Flask as below.

[image]

The file list in the `wwwroot` path in the Kudu tool or FTP shown as below.

[image]

Then, I modified the code `views.py` in the `FlaskWebProject1` directory. And it works.
[image]

It seems to be more simple. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been figthing the same issue for a while, I have only be able to workaround it by changing the pricing tier associated to the "service plan" to S2 Standard. If I try to use S1 Standard I run into the same issues.